# how to simplify two input with different jQuery events but have the same function

Tags: jquery, function, event-handling

I have two input with different events but they run the same function. My first attempt is this:

```
var inputa = $("input[name='inputa']");
var inputb = $("input[name='inputb']");

inputa.on('change keyup blur', function()
{
    // Logic
});

inputb.on('blur', function()
{
    // Logic
});
```

It worked but i thought it was such a waste and maybe there's a way to simplify this. I did some research and found this:

```
inputa.on('change keyup blur', myFunction());
inputb.on('blur', myFunction());

function myFunction()
{
    // Logic
}
```

I put the logic into a function and put it on the respective events. But it didn't work. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: `inputa.on('change keyup blur', myFunction());` ---> `inputa.on('change keyup blur', myFunction);`

Comment: Waw, it worked. Thank you @Pang

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you have the `()` in:

```
inputb.on('blur', myFunction());
```

You are invoking that function immediately whereas what you want is to pass the function as reference :

```
inputb.on('blur', myFunction);
```